# SSH Tunneling HTTPS traffic through 2 Servers

Tags: ssh, tunneling

What I'm trying to determine is how do you tunnel HTTPS traffic through more than 1 host?  Normally what I do when I have to jump through 1 host is the following:

```
# URL Access Tunnel: https://127.0.0.1:1234
ssh -L 1234:TARGET_SERVER:443 jumphost.foo.com
```

Then I can connect my browser to `https://127.0.0.1:1234` and I'm good to go. But now I have a 2nd jumphost I need to tunnel through, but I can't seem to make a similar SSH command work.

Diagram:

> Laptop -> Jumphost1 -> Jumphost2 -> Remote_HTTP_Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-J` (or `ProxyJump` ssh_config keyword) to connect first to `jumphost1` and then to `jumphost2`:

```
 ssh -L 1234:TARGET_SERVER:443 -J jumphost1 jumphost2
```

You may use `N` intermediate jumphosts in your ssh chain with

```
 ssh -L 1234:TARGET_SERVER:443 -J jumphost1,jumphost2,...,jumphostN jumphostN+1
```

See the [OpenSSH Cookbook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two) and the [OpenSSH man page](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump) for a `ProxyJump` overview.